# AttributeError: 'HtmlTestResult' object has no attribute '_count_relevant_tb_levels'. Did you mean: '_is_relevant_tb_level'?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

import unittest
import HtmlTestRunner
from selenium import webdriver
class Test_OrangeHRM(unittest.TestCase):
@classmethod
def setUpClass(cls):
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
cls.driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
cls.driver.maximize_window()
def test_HomePage(self):
self.driver.get("https://opensource-demo.orangehrmlive.com/")
self.assertEqual("OrangeHR", self.driver.title, "Webpage Title Is Not Matching")

```
def test_Login(self):
    self.driver.get("https://opensource-demo.orangehrmlive.com/")
    self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='txtUsername']").send_keys("Admin")
    self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='txtPassword']").send_keys("admin123")
    self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='btnLogin']").click()
    self.assertEqual("OrangeHRM123", self.driver.title, "Webpage Title Is Not Matching")
@classmethod
def tearDownClass(cls):
    cls.driver.quit()
    print("Test Completed")
```

if **name**=="**main**":
unittest.main(testRunner=HtmlTestRunner.HTMLTestRunner(output="C:/Users/HP/PycharmProjects/seleniumPython/Reports"))

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It is a test with html report in selenium python runned using html test-Runner.But after adding a definition function in the result.py which was created by the phycharm ide when running my code, its not showing any error and my program is working.Thank You.

Comment: We are also facing this issue in ubuntu 22.04, python 3.10,  html-testRunner==1.2.1
Any workaround?

Answer (score 5):

This works for me.
Apparently the "_count_relevant_tb_levels" is not available in the newest versions, so you need to go to the source code of the HtmlTestRunner package.

1. Inside the HtmlTestRunner folder of the package you have installed, look for result.py
2. Find the "_exc_info_to_string" method of the "HtmlTestResult" class.
3. Replace these lines:

   ```
    if exctype is test.failureException:
        # Skip assert*() traceback levels
        length = self._count_relevant_tb_levels(tb)
        msg_lines = traceback.format_exception(exctype, value, tb, length)
   ```

with

```
    if exctype is test.failureException:
        # Skip assert*() traceback levels
        msg_lines = traceback.format_exception(exctype, value, tb)
```